# Orthonormal basis for $C([0,1])$

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, inner-products, orthonormal

Consider the vector space $C([0,1])$ of continuous complex-valued function on the unit interval. Endow it with the inner product $\int_{0}^1f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx$.

I want to show that the set $\{e^{2\pi i kt}: k\in \mathbb Z\}$ is orthonormal.  I'm aware that a complex integral can be written in the form $\int_{a}^{b} u(x)dx +i\int_{a}^b v(x)dx$, but I'm not sure how to carry out the computations here.

I'd appreciate it if someone could give an explanation or point me to a source that includes this proof, (which I think would be somewhat common, given the relation to Fourier analysis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just do the direct computation. Let's denote $e_k := e^{2\pi i k t}, k\in \mathbb{Z}$ then for $k \neq l$ we have
\begin{equation}
<e_k,e_l> = \int_0^1 e_k \bar e_l dt = \int_0^1 e^{2\pi i k t} e^{-2\pi i l t}dt = \int_0^1 e^{2\pi i(k - l)t}dt = \frac{1}{2\pi i (k-l)}(e^{2\pi i(k - l)} - e^0) = 0.
\end{equation}
But for $k = l$ we have
\begin{equation}
<e_k,e_k> = \int_0^1 e_k \bar e_k dt = \int_0^1 e^{2\pi i k t} e^{-2\pi i k t}dt = \int_0^1 1 dt = 1.
\end{equation}

Answer (score -1):

Establish the relationship for integers $m$ and $n$
$$
\int_{0}^{1} e^{2\pi i m t} e^{-2\pi i n t} dt =
\int_{0}^{1} e^{2\pi i (m - n ) t} dt =
\begin{cases}
  1 & m=n \\
  0 & m\ne n
\end{cases}
$$

---

When $m\ne n$,
$$
\int e^{2\pi i (m - n ) t} dt = 
\frac{i \left(1 - e^{2 i \pi  (m-n)}\right)}{2 \pi  (m-n)}
$$
When $m=n$
$$
\int e^{2\pi i (m - n ) t} dt = 
\int 0 \,dt = 0
$$

Comment: The last integral is not correct. $\int_0^1 e^{0} dt = \int_0^1 1 dt = 1$. Not sure about the other integrals in the way you ahve them written but isn't $\int_0^1 e^{2\pi i k t} = 0$ for $ k \ne 0$?